# Have not been rendered for the layout page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i was deleted my `_Layout.cshtml` from shared folder and create a new `_Layout.cshtml` but unfortunately it is not working.

throwing this

> The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Scripts".

so my page working if set

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = null;
}
```

or

```
  @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
```

so i am not interested to set this way , cause I have 100+ view page any help me . How  can I do this

Thank you

Comment: Your new layout is missing `@RenderSection("Scripts", false)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes , missing . now it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your layout page you should see

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", true)
```

or

```
@RenderSection("Scripts")
```

this basically instructs the interpreter that any page that using this layout should have a scripts section such as :

```
@section Scripts {
//whatever goes here
}
```

if you don't want that section just remove @RenderSection from the layout page, or if you want it to be optional, change the second parameter to false in the `@RenderSection("Scripts", false)`. otherwise add the scripts section to your sub pages as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that the  layout is in the proper shared folder? And if so can you please  post the header part of the layout?

Hope it helps :)